# Pack divs of random width and height together as tightly as possible

Tags: html, css, grid, pack

I don't know if this can be done fairly simply just with CSS and a bit of JavaScript, like I'm trying to do below. Some people have said it can't be done. I'm hoping you can show me the way.

I want to pack divs of random width and height together as tightly as possible. I want to create a sequence of about 100 divs with random widths and heights (random within a given range of values) such that they 'float' together to create more or less as little white space as possible.

Here's the idea. But this creates a lot of white space between/among the divs, which is not what we want.

```js
init();

function init() {
  var n = 100;
  var minWidth = 20;
  var maxWidth = 50;
  var minHeight = 10;
  var maxHeight = 40;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var width = randomInteger(minWidth, maxWidth);
    var height = randomInteger(minHeight, maxHeight);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("aDiv");
    div.style.width = width + 'px';
    div.style.height = height + 'px';
    var color = randomColor();
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'hsl(' + color.hue + ',' + color.saturation + '%,' + color.lightness + '%)';
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function randomColor() {
  var hueCenter = 167;
  var hueRange = 25;
  var saturationCenter = 50;
  var saturationRange = 15;
  var lightnessCenter = 50;
  var lightnessRange = 20;
  var hue = randomInteger(hueCenter - hueRange, hueCenter + hueRange);
  var saturation = randomInteger(saturationCenter - saturationRange, saturationCenter + saturationRange);
  var lightness = randomInteger(lightnessCenter - lightnessRange, lightnessCenter + lightnessRange);
  return {
    hue: hue,
    saturation: saturation,
    lightness: lightness
  };

}

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  // Returns a random integer between min and max. 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
.aDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `display: flex;` on the `div` with ID `container` without any additional property on the children divs (i.e. `div`s with class `aDiv`), it would help. You only CSS would be:

```css
#container {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: flex-end; //put the appropriate value to position your children divs
}
```

Here in flexbox, the property `align-content` is the key. It is used for aligning items with multiple lines.

The possible values are:
`align-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | stretch;`

[image: align-content]

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thank you, Shraddha. It does not seem to work. The key to my situation is that the heights of the divs are randomly determined at run-time. All the solutions I've looked at so far are for situations where the height is constant or multiples of a base height.